# Swift & NSTableView - Simply select a row

Tags: xcode, select, swift, row, nstableview

I'd like to programatically select a row in my NSTableView, with just one column.

```
func selectColumnIndexes(_ indexes: NSIndexSet!,
    byExtendingSelection extend: Bool)
```

I have been playing around with this, but I am not sure how to write "Select row #2".
Do I have to start with the variable connected to the `@IBOutlet` of my Table View? I have to indicate it is about my NSTableView somehow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Swift 4 Solution**

I created an extension to make a little easier to do this.  Also if you implemented a click action on the table view cell this will invoke it as well

```
extension NSTableView {
    func selectRow(at index: Int) {
        selectRowIndexes(.init(integer: index), byExtendingSelection: false)
        if let action = action {
            perform(action)
        }
    }
}

/// USAGE:
NSTableView().selectRow(at: 0)
```

Answer (score 9):

@Isaiah answer in Swift 3.0:

```
.selectRowIndexes(NSIndexSet(index: 0) as IndexSet, byExtendingSelection: false)
```

Answer (score 7):

Okay, I've got it. It turned out to be

```
@IBOutlet weak var NoteTableView: NSTableView!
NoteTableView.selectRowIndexes(NSIndexSet(index: 0), byExtendingSelection: false)
```

I couldn't quite figure out the part with `NSIndexSet`. I was fiddling around with `init()`, which turned out to be unnecessary.