# How to programmatically select a row in UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to select a row in a UITableView programmatically using Swift 1.2.

This is the simple code:

```
var index = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(index, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle)
self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: index)
```

The above gives me the following error:

> **Cannot invoke 'selectRowAtIndexPath' with an argument list of type '(NSIndexPath!, animated: Bool, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition)'**

What is wrong with my Swift 1.2 code?

My UItableView has been created in IB in the UIViewController that I am trying to call the code above. 
When I put the code in a UITableViewController the compiler does not give any errors.
Do I need to embed a UITableViewController in a container or is there another way?

Comment: Nope, the second line compiles just fine.

Comment: Did you define a `tableView` property in the view controller (and connect it to the table view in the IB) ? Could this be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733126/swift-cannot-invoke-reloaddata-with-no-arguments ?

Comment: @MartinR I did define & connect a tableView property in my VC using  IBOutlet weak var menuTable: UITableView! However I don't have a UITableViewController that controls this tableView. I can't replace my VC with a TVC as I need other elements in my iPad project. My VC has a main container in it which reacts to selections in the tableView. I have tried to create a container in my VC and then embed a TVC in it. That displays the menu items correctly, but then I have a problem with changing what the main container shows (based on the selection in the menu). Specifically it has an issue with:

Comment: @Mikee: If your the table view property is called "menuTable" then you should call it as `self. menuTable.selectRowAtIndexPath(...)` and similarly for the next statement.

Comment: @MartinR `@IBAction func didChangeValue(sender: AnyObject) {
var newController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(sender as! String) as! UIViewController
 let oldController = childViewControllers.last as! UIViewController
 oldController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)` [snip]  It has no idea about the oldController (that is part of the VC that the TVC is embedded in. All I need is to be able to programatically select the row! :/

Comment: @MartinR Awesome that worked! So simple – your help is much appreciated! Do you care to put your comment as an answer so I can credit you with the right answer?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The statement

```
self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(index, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle)
```

assumes that `tableView` is a property of the view controller, connected
to a table view in the Storyboard. A `UITableViewController`, for example, already has this 
property.

In your case, the view controller is a not a table view controller
but a subclass of a `UIViewController`. It also has an outlet that is
connected to the table view, but it is not called 
`tableView` but `menuTable`. Then of course you have to call

```
self.menuTable.selectRowAtIndexPath(index, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle)
```

to select a row of that table view.

The strange error messages are caused by the fact that 
`self.tableView` can also be understood by the compiler as a
"curried function" (compare http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/).

Comment: Swift 3:

`self.tableView.selectRow(at: index, animated: true, scrollPosition: .middle)`

Comment: @MartinR As we are doing UI Selction, doesn't need `selectRowAtIndexPath(index` inside `DispatchQueue.main.async` ?

Answer (score 94):

### **Swift 3** to **Swift 5** Solution

***Selecting a Row***

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
myTableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .bottom)
myTableView.delegate?.tableView!(myTableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
```

***DeSelecting a Row***

```
let deselectIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 7, section: 0)
myTableView.deselectRow(at: deselectIndexPath, animated: true)
myTableView.delegate?.tableView!(myTableView, didDeselectRowAt: indexPath)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - I didn't know you had to directly call the delegate methods! To avoid possible crashes I'd swap the `!` for a `?` in `myTableView.delegate?.tableView!`

Answer (score 20):

Use below code,after loading your table view with data:

```
let rowToSelect:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0);  //slecting 0th row with 0th section
self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelect, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None);
```

now,you have to manually call **didSelectRowAtIndexPath:** delegate method using below code:

```
self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: rowToSelect); //Manually trigger the row to select
```

Thanks.

Comment: @ShaileshChandavar Pankaj is right... why can't you call didSelectRowAtIndexPath manually ? suppose initially you have to select a particular row, how can you achieve this ?

Comment: "Calling this method does not cause the delegate to receive a tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: or tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: message, nor does it send UITableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification notifications to observers." [docs for selectRowAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:)

Comment: But how does this explain the *compiler error* reported in the question?

Comment: My UItableView has been created in IB in the UIViewController that I am trying to call the code above. When I put the code in a UITableViewController the compiler does not give any errors. Do I need to embed a UITableViewController in a container or is there another way?

Answer (score 14):

### Swift 3.x

if you want to do it at the 'cell-creation', you can do it like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = TableViewCell()
    let item = items[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text    = item.title

    if (item.checked) {
        tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Using **Swift 2.x**, as described by [Pankaj purohit answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31248252/1894067) the correct method is:

```
func tapRowAtIndex(index:Int) {
        let rowToSelect:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
        self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelect, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
        self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: rowToSelect)
}
```

Keep in mind that if you call this method from an external class for example, you dont know when tableView has finished its loading, so what's the possibilities?, how to workaround this problem? :

**Step one**: create a class boolean var

```
var automatingTap: Bool = false
```

**Step two**: check when the table finish its loading and launch an "end operations" method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{
    let lastRowIndex = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0)
    if indexPath.row == lastRowIndex - 1 {
       endOperations()
    }
}

func endOperations() 
{
   print("finished loading")
   if automatingTap {
        tapRowAtIndex(0)
        automatingTap = false
   }
}
```

**Step three**: call my tableView class from another class

for example:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue!.identifier == "DetailsTableView" {
        let viewController:ViewController = segue!.destinationViewController as ViewController
        viewController.automatingTap = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

***Reusable function with validation of table size***

Swift 4 and 5

This reusable function works and validate the size of table.

```
func selectRow(tableView: UITableView, position: Int) {
    let sizeTable = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
    guard position >= 0 && position < sizeTable else { return }
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: position, section: 0)
    tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .middle)
}
```

you can use it in this way

```
selectRow(tableView: myTableView, position: pos)
```

or you can implement this extension:

```
extension UITableView {
    func selectRow(row: Int, section: Int = 0) {
        let sizeTable = self.numberOfRows(inSection: section)
        guard row >= 0 && row < sizeTable else { return }
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
        self.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .middle)
    }
}
```

and you can use it in this way:

```
mytableView.selectRow(row: pos, section: 0)
```

or

```
mytableView.selectRow(row: pos)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2**:

***Select one or more Rows***

```
let ndx:IndexSet = [1]
// or:  let ndx:IndexSet = [1, 2, 3]; // etc
tableview?.selectRowIndexes(ndx, byExtendingSelection: false);
```

***Deselect a Single Row***

```
tableview?.deselectRow(current)
```

Note that if you have (*func tableViewSelectionDidChange(...)*) implemented, that will be triggered by the above.

Also see Charlton Provatas' answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48696458/352920 for an extension to NSTableView, that provides a simple

```
tableview?.selectRow(at:)
```