# Deselect row in tableview after programmatically selecting

Tags: ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I followed this thread first: [How to programmatically select a row in UITableView in Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247991/how-to-programmatically-select-a-row-in-uitableview-in-swift-1-2-xcode-6-4/40590015)

Which did help for the selection, but when I tap the screen to select another row, the previously (programmatically) set row will not trigger the deselect message.  The cells that are selected naturally (by tapping the screen), do receive the deselect message.

I need that row that is programmatically selected to receive the deselect message (non-programmatically).

(I'm working in a UITableView subclass - so it's not a delegate, it's overrides).

[Example Video](https://vimeo.com/252607718)

My code:

```
        if let selectedRow = viewModel.selectedRow {
        defaultSelectedPath = IndexPath(row: selectedRow, section: 0)
        if let defaultSelectedPath = defaultSelectedPath {
            let selectedCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: defaultSelectedPath)
            self.tableView.selectRow(at: defaultSelectedPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
            self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: defaultSelectedPath)

            selectedCell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
    }
```

Hack Fix:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark

    if let defaultSelectedPath = self.defaultSelectedPath {
        if indexPath != defaultSelectedPath {
            cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: defaultSelectedPath)
            tableView.deselectRow(at: defaultSelectedPath, animated: false)
            self.tableView(self.tableView, didDeselectRowAt: defaultSelectedPath)
            cell?.accessoryType = .none
        }
        self.defaultSelectedPath = nil
    }
}
```

Please tell me there's a better way to do this.

Comment: I had to write a bunch of stupid hack code, but I think I got it...

Comment: are you want to select only 1 row at a time right?

Comment: Yes, but with a default value that is programmatically set and shown at load time.

Comment: Did you tried below code?

Answer (score 1):

you can use :-

```
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = true
```

on `viewDidLoad()`