# How to select a row programmatically in table View ? (Swift 4.0)

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableViewController, my data source work well, but i can't select a row programmatically.

I have tried:

```
class DocumentTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition(rawValue: 0)!)
     }
}
```

when I run, the tableView selects nothing.
How can I solve that ?

Comment: at that point (viewDidLoad) have you set the tableView datasource and delegate? does it have data at this point?

Comment: did you set the delegate?

Comment: no need for delegate and datasource in   UITableViewController

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programmatically select a row in UITableView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247991/how-to-programmatically-select-a-row-in-uitableview-in-swift)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your line is very earlier try it in

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition(rawValue: 0)!) 
}
```

or this inside `viewDidLoad`

```
tableView.reloadData()
tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition(rawValue: 0)!)
```

Answer (score 1):

in swift 5:

```
tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableView.ScrollPosition(rawValue: 0)!)
```